# Hide a view tab if it has no results

Tags: views

I have a view which has 5 menu tabs. I want to hide the tab if it doesn't have any results. Can anyone please help me with the suggestions.

Comment: [How to hide a TAB menu made by Views if the view itself return no results: is there a better way to accomplish this?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1485188)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with Jquery
Check for the class "view-empty", if this div has inner div, then that means it has some content, if not hide that parent tab div.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing hooks as below

function custom_tabs_hide_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name, $route_match) {

// Check if the current route matches the route where your Views is being displayed.

if ($route_name === 'entity.view.your_view_id.page_1') {

```
// Replace 'your_view_id' with the actual ID of your view.
// Check if the View has no results.

$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('your_view_id');
```

// Replace 'your_view_id' with the actual ID of your view.

```
$view->setDisplay('page_1'); // Replace 'page_1' with the display ID of your view.

$view->execute();

if (empty($view->result)) {
  // Hide the tab.
  unset($data['tabs']['view-id.your_view_id-page_1']);
}
```

}
}